# How to allocate more memory to your program( GCC)

Tags: c, gcc

I want to allocate more memory to program.l What is the gcc flag that allows you to do so?

FYI what I am trying to do is create a very large matrix( really large) which is gonna go through compression algorithms later. So there is no way I can avoid creating such a large matrix to store data.

Comment: How big is really large?  100 x 100? 1000 x 1000? 10,000 x 10,000?

Comment: @JeremyP: Sarcasm unnecessary. This question pops-up high on StOv search. When in doubt, interpret the Q in most challenging way, so e.g.: allocate 95% of your physical memory, i.e. 60GB.

Comment: @PMarecki there was no sarcasm in my comment.  "really large" really doesn't give us any idea of the problem the questioner is having.  For instance, it might just be "too large for the stack" or it might be "too large for the available RAM" or some other definition of "too large".  In each case the answer would be different.  The most challenging way might be too large for physical RAM for which the answer would be wrong if the questioner is merely getting a stack overflow because he is allocating his array on the stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is very unclear, but I suspect that you are trying to create a large multidimensional array (matrix) as a local variable (auto variable) to some function (possibly main) and this is failing.

```
int foo(int boo, int doo) {
    int big_array[REALLY_BIG];
    ...
```

This would fail because C compilers try to make room for variables like this on the programs system stack.  A compiler may just fail upon attempting to *think* about something that big being on the stack (especially with alignment issues that might make it bigger) or it may generate code to try to do this and either the CPU can't run it because stack pointer relative indexing is limited or because the OS has placed limits on the size of the program's system stack.

There may be ways to change OS limits, but if it is a CPU limit you are just going to have to do things differently.

For some things the simplest thing to do use just use global or `static` variables for large sized data such as this.  Doing this you end up allocating the space for the data either at compile time or at program load time (just prior to run time), but limits your ability to have more than one copy since you have to plan ahead to declare enough global variables to hold everything you want to be *live* at the same time.

You could also try using `malloc` or `calloc` to allocate the memory for you.

A third option is (if you are using a *nix system) to memory map a file containing the matrix.  Look into the `mmap` system call for this.

An added benefit of  using `mmap` or `static` or global variables is that under most operating systems the virtual memory manager can use the original file (the file containing the matrix for mmap, or the executable file for static or global) as swap space for the memory that the data uses.  This makes it so that your program may be able to run without putting too much of a strain on the physical memory or virtual memory manager.

Answer (score 4):

If the matrix is really large you might have to allocate memory in smaller segments so it can find room in the virtual memory space. On 32-bit Windows I have found you simply cannot get anything bigger than about 980 MB in a single allocation. On Linux it is pushing it to try to get more than about 1.5 GB.

In a 64-bit system you can get a lot more.

But in any case, I would recommend using a matrix library that can handle the memory and algorithms for you. There are many subtle tricks to making fast matrix computations. Tricks with threads, computing in cache-sized blocks, prefetching data, SSE vector ops, etc.

You might want to look into using the math libraries from either Intel or AMD.

Comment: From the 32-bit Window's perspective, you can do better using VirtualAlloc directly.  Though when committing memory, your process is still limited to 2GB reserved memory, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slavao/archive/2005/01/27/361678.aspx for these exciting details.

Comment: The Intel IPP product contains a math library for both windows and linux, http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-ipp/

Comment: @Chris O: Lately I have tried and tried to get a reliable 1 GB alloc out of 32-bit windows. VirtualAlloc will *not* do it.

Comment: I can do this quite easily, but only tried the large allocations from a small test app, which might have a much better chance than from a realistic application.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any special gcc flags.

Use `malloc` to allocate your array dynamically at runtime.

If you are somehow forced to use a static array, or if your environment is set up by default to limit your program's access to virtual memory, you may need to use the `ulimit` command.

```
ulimit -v unlimited
ulimit -d unlimited
```

Otherwise, you need to specify more clearly the error you are getting that prevents you from getting sufficient memory, and probably also tell us how big your matrix is.

Answer (score 2):

Use the heap! `malloc()` and friends are your friends.